# Apache Beam - What happens with Windows/Triggers after multiple GroupByKey?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

The windowing section of the Beam programming model guide shows a
window defined and used in the GroupyByKey transform after a ParDo.
([section 7.1.1](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-constraints)).

How long does a window remain in scope for an element?

Let's imagine a pipeline like this:

```
my_pcollection = p | MySourceOfData()

results_pcoll = (my_pcollection
                 | beam.WindowInto(..., triggering=...)
                 | beam.GroupByKey()
                 | beam.ParDo(DoSomeFormattingFn())
                 | beam.Combine.Globally(sum))
```

Suppose that the first window is aggregating by key, but in the
second window you may want to combine elements across all keys.

How will the `results_pcoll` look like? Will it be windowed? Will it be per-key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Beam, it is important to remember that *every element has a window associated to it*.

In the code snippet, elements in `my_pcollection` are associated to the **Global Window**. When you add a `beam.WindowInto`, you're adding a window to each element - and when they go into the `GroupByKey`, elements will be grouped **by both: key, and window**.

---

When you go downstream to a `ParDo`, and a `Combine`, your elements **continue to have the same window**, and the **same trigger**.

This happens because Beam tries to allow your data to continue to flow through your pipeline, so it keeps the same window and trigger semantics.

---

With those considerations, your `results_pcoll` will have the same window, and the same trigger semantics that you added at the beginning of the pipeline.

By combining Globally, you'll have a single aggregation over all keys, but you will also have one aggregation **for each window**.

Comment: You should write the docs, this answer is way better than anything in the official ones.